# How to access Shopify API in liquid or javascript variables in liquid?

Tags: shopify, liquid

From what I can find, it seems that this may be impossible. There must be someway to do this though. All I want to do is get some information from the API, and pass it to a liquid variable. Maybe there's another way.

Comment: You'd be better off describing what info you actually want to use. There are sometimes ways to get specific information but there is not a general solution (other than creating an app that pulls info and writes it to a theme snippet.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since liquid renders server side you can't pass javascript variables into the template engine. However you can embed liquid template code in javascript functions. There's a post on the shopify forums with some example code that may help: [Pass variable from Java script to liquid?](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/pass-variable-from-java-script-to-liquid-143782)

for example:

```
 $(function() {
  new Shopify.OptionSelectors("product-select", { product: {{ product | json }}, onVariantSelected: selectCallback });

  // Add label if only one product option and it isn't 'Title'.
  {% if product.options.size == 1 and product.options.first != 'Title' %}
  $('.selector-wrapper:eq(0)').prepend('<label>{{ product.options.first }}</label>');
  {% endif %}

  // Auto-select first available variant on page load.
  {% assign found_one_in_stock = false %}
  {% for variant in product.variants %}
    {% if variant.available and found_one_in_stock == false %}
      {% assign found_one_in_stock = true %}
      {% for option in product.options %}
        $('.single-option-selector:eq({{ forloop.index0 }})').val({{ variant.options[forloop.index0] | json }}).trigger('change');
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}

});
```